# PHP Laravel Validation data key names

Tags: laravel

I got such problem.
What I want to do - is to make 1 place for validation rules for a user data. These data consists of Patient, Address and other objects.
So I created rules:

```
protected function validationRules()
{
    return [
        'Patient.firstName' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'Patient.lastName'        => 'required|string',
        'Patient.sex'        => 'required|string',
        'Address.city'        => 'required|string',
        'Address.states'        => 'required|string',
        'Address.address1'        => 'required|string|min:2',
        'Address.zip'        => 'required|string|min:2',
        'Phone.mobileArea'        => 'string|min:3|required_with:Phone.mobilePhone',
        'Phone.mobilePhone'        => 'string|min:7|required_with:Phone.mobileArea',
        'Phone.homePhone'        => 'string|min:7|required_with:Phone.homeArea',
        'Phone.homeArea'        => 'string|min:3|required_with:Phone.homePhone',
    ];
}
```

In form i have inputs like

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" name="Patient[firstName]" value="{{ $user->getFirstName() }}" required autofocus placeholder="First Name">
```

And on save everything works correctly.
The code 
        `$this->validate($request, $this->validationRules());`

Performs validation very well. BUT....

On another place, when I want to show that some information is missing in the user profile, I perform such validation and its failed:

```
$validator = Validator::make([
        'Patient[firstName]' => $user->getFirstName(),
        'Patient[lastName]'        => $user->getLastName(),
        'Patient.lastName'        => $user->getLastName(),
        'Patient->lastName'        => $user->getLastName(),
        'Patient.sex'        => $user->getSex(),
        'Address.city'        => $address->getCity(),
        'Address.states'        => $address->getState(),
        'Address.address1'        => $address->getStreet1(),
        'Address.zip'        => $address->getZip(),
        'Phone.mobileArea'        => $mobilePhone->getArea(),
        'Phone.mobilePhone'        => $mobilePhone->getNumber(),
        'Phone.homePhone'        => $homePhone->getArea(),
        'Phone.homeArea'        => $homePhone->getNumber(),
    ], $this->validationRules());
```

As you can see, i tried different variations of naming Patient->lastName key in data array. But i still have error that last name is required.
When i print validator i can see such structure:

```
    Validator {#300 ▼
  #data: array:12 [▼
    "Patient[firstName]" => ""
    "Patient[lastName]" => "Colohanin"
    "Patient->lastName" => "Colohanin"
    "Patient->sex" => "female"
    "Address->city" => "GOSHEN2"
    "Address->states" => "NY"
    "Address->address1" => "Aleco Russo 59/1 a.68"
    "Address->zip" => "109242"
    "Phone->mobileArea" => "793"
    "Phone->mobilePhone" => "906990"
    "Phone->homePhone" => "022"
    "Phone->homeArea" => "3322278"
  ]
  #initialRules: array:1 [▼
    "Patient.lastName" => "required|string"
  ]

}
```

As I understand, the validator has rules for "Patient.lastName" but in data array Laravel transform this key to object and Validator can't find this key in data bag. In result, I have error - > patient last name required(for testing purposes, I removed other rules)

**So there is my question. Does anyone know, how to set data array in "dot" sintancs? How should i name "Patient.lastName" in data array(first parameter in Validator::make())?**

The rewriting keys using underscore doesn't accept(patient_firstName)

Comment: The laravel documentation states, that you need to use the dot-syntax in `  Validator::make() ` . The bug must be somewhere else.

Comment: As you can see, i tried dot -syntax, but vaidator cant find it

Comment: @xcy7e웃 Youre comment helps me to find array_set function thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->validate($request->get('Patient'), $this->validationRules());
```

form input:
all name changes it to :

```
 <input id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" name="Patient[firstName]" value="{{ $user->getFirstName() }}" required autofocus placeholder="First Name">
 <input id="mobileArea" type="text" class="form-control" name="Patient[mobileArea]" value="{{ $user->mobileArea() }}" required autofocus placeholder="mobileArea"
```

>

and change all validationrules using:

```
protected function validationRules()
{
    return [
        'Patient.firstName' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'Patient.lastName'        => 'required|string',
        'Patient.sex'        => 'required|string',
        'Patient.city'        => 'required|string',
        'Patient.states'        => 'required|string',
        'Patient.address1'        => 'required|string|min:2',
        'Patient.zip'        => 'required|string|min:2',
        'Patient.mobileArea'        => 'string|min:3|required_with:Patient.mobilePhone',
        'Patient.mobilePhone'        => 'string|min:7|required_with:Patient.mobileArea',
        'Patient.homePhone'        => 'string|min:7|required_with:Patient.homeArea',
        'Patient.homeArea'        => 'string|min:3|required_with:Patient.homePhone',
    ];
}
```

Hope it help

Comment: As i wrote - The rewriting keys using underscore doesn't accept(patient_firstName). Sorry but its unacceptable

Comment: @ColohaninNik i didn't mean to do it Patient_firstName, i will edit my answer

Comment: In save action everything works correctly, $this->validate($request, $this->validationRules()); corectly validate save request. Problem was in show page,  where i dont have POST,GET, but i have to show user that some of his data is not valid

Comment: @ColohaninNik i see, i'm sorry, i don't get the question. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly i found that laravel helper have array_set helper for such arrays.
So in result:

```
$data = [
        'Patient[firstName]' => $user->getFirstName(),
        'Patient[lastName]'        => $user->getLastName(),
        'Patient["lastName"]'        => $user->getLastName(),
        'Patient.lastName'        => $user->getLastName(),
        'Patient->lastName'        => $user->getLastName(),
        'Address.city'        => $address->getCity(),
        'Address.states'        => $address->getState(),
        'Address.address1'        => $address->getStreet1(),
        'Address.zip'        => $address->getZip(),
        'Phone.mobileArea'        => $mobilePhone->getArea(),
        'Phone.mobilePhone'        => $mobilePhone->getNumber(),
        'Phone.homePhone'        => $homePhone->getArea(),
        'Phone.homeArea'        => $homePhone->getNumber(),
    ];
```

Fails validation, but if you add elements throw array_set helper it helps
[array_set](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#arrays)

```
        array_set($data, 'Patient.lastName'       , $user->getLastName());
```

After that, validation by lastName is no longer fails.
Hope it helps somebody